# Find vector and parametric vector of a line

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I have a line that is perpendicular to a plane. This perpendicular line is $3i-2j+6k$. I've also been given that the line passes through $A(2,3,0)$.

I'm unsure on how to represent this line as a vector and parametric vector that passes through $A$. In fact, I'm a little confused about the difference between a vector and a parametric vector.

Comment: ...and the question is...? Also: do you have some ideas, insights...? And also: what you call there "perpendicular line" isn't a line at all.

Comment: @Timbuc Try to be a little more helpful, and a little less arrogant.

Comment: @JordanGlen Thank you so much. Do you have some *mathematical*  ideas for the OP now that you've guessed what (s)he means, or you'd rather bother people around instead?

Comment: I think this is not a constructive discussion, clearly Burke is a new user and maybe with our help he/she will be a very good one in the future. This site is for all of us, to help each other.

Answer (score 0):

You have the **vector** $v=3i-2j+6k$, and that vector defines a line that passes through the point $A=(2,3,0)$ and which parametric equation is $l=A+tv$, so I assume that the parametric vector you are finding is $w(t)=(2+3t)i+(3-2t)j+6k\ $ which is another form of writing the same line.